# Scheduler without CRON JOBS in RAILS 4.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I want to create a Scheduling functionality where we need to call the external API and these operations need to be processed on background. How can we do it without using any OS CRON JOBS. I'm new to rails, please give me some suggestions

I have seen some gems like Whenever which uses OS CRON's but my requirement is without using those CRON's.

Comment: have you googled for any other options because they are out there.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my personal projects, I used Rufus Scheduler which worked well. I was using it to make API calls to twitter and fetch tweets and cache them.

It also had a clear documentation here.[Rufus-Scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler)

I guess, it uses OS's CRON jobs functionality to schedule jobs from Ruby.

Hope this helps!